# VLC Media Player with Ubuntu 20.04 and MP4 videos

Tags: vlc

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 (clean install, replacing 18.04). Now when I try to play MP4 videos VLC tells me it cannot play them. My other laptop (Win 10) has the same version of VLC installed (3.0.8). Transferring videos via memory stick to this PC replays them perfectly.
Any ideas please?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: Thank you. I tried that from terminal and got to a point where a Microsoft EULA banner appeared (which I could nothing with, because it was an image within terminal). Nothing happened after about an hour so I closed terminal - against a warning that a process was running. Thereafter everything else I tried to do on the pc was blocked because of some incomplete task. I have almost run out of ideas and patience so I think I will go back to 18.04 where I know VLC works OK. Meanwhile your help is appreciated.

Comment: When EULA appears, press `tab` to change selected option. When you select `ok` or `continue` or something similar, press enter. If your pc says something about incomplete task restart your computer and run `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` again. If the problem persists run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`.